# Timestamp vs Date -time in Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I have option of storing date in mongo as **ISO oject** or **timestamp** in mongo.

Which one is more advisable and beneficial to use and why??

Answer (score 4):

`Timestamp` data type is not for use by the end user ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongotimestamp.php ), this means that if you store a timestamp it will have no special abilities for date manipulation as it will be just an `int`.

The "special" abilities you can get are mostly confined to Map Reduce and the aggregation framework whereby the valid date object (in the aggregation framework) is really the only reliable way to do time comparison.

So even though you can store the timestamp `int`, and it would be smaller than the `ISODate()` I would personally recommend not to.